# URL Conf - Serving views at the root URL and non root URLs within one app

Tags: django, urlconf

I've run into a problem configuring the `url.py` files in a new project. I have one app, which contains two views. The first view should appear at myurl.com, while the other should appear at `myurl.com/foo`. `myurl.com` appears without trouble but `myurl.com/foo` shows a 404 page not found error.

The `url.py` at the project level looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
)
```

And the `url.py` at the app level looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.book_search, name='book_search'),
    url(r'^foo/', views.myapp, name='myapp')
)
```

I understand that that django is taking the URL that is submitted and checks it against the url patterns defined at the project level, but I don't know how to direct it to `myapp` without hosting all of `myapp` at some url that is not at the root, i.e. `myapp.com/bar` and `myapp.com/bar/foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
```

Remove the `^$` here. This would force all included URLs to match only if starting with "the end", i.e. nothing.